# Is this pipe for gas or water?

Tags: water, gas, range

I am thinking on taking advantage of the black friday and replace my old electric range with a gas range. Now, there is this pipe next to the electric stove and I was wondering if it is a gas pipe. [image: In this picture you can see the electric range on the left side]. [image: This is a closer look of the pipe in question]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. To me, it looks like one, but that's won't be enough for you. You need to get a plumber to check it out.

Comment: Or if it’s exposed below the kitchen follow it.

Comment: I will follow it below the kitchen and see what I find. I was also thinking in shutting off the main gas line to the house and remove the cap to see if there is some gas smell there. Would that be OK or is that something that the gas company would have to do?

Comment: Ok, so at the end a professional came and we traced the main gas line and found where it drops from the attic to the kitchen area.